# Creating new Columns based on custom fields in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to create a new column based on the results from one of my columns but I'm having trouble creating the new column based on some of my current results and its criteria.

This is how my data currently looks -

| Number | Name | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1789 | Brandon | 12/20/2021 | Pending |
| 1789 | Brandon | 12/22/2021 | Approved |
| 1553 | Jake | 10/05/2021 | Approved |
| 1553 | Jake | 11/10/2021 | Canceled |
| 1997 | Smith | 09/08/2021 | Approved |
| 1997 | Smith | 09/11/2021 | Transferred |
| 1338 | James | 11/05/2021 | Approved |
| 1338 | James | 11/10/2021 | Canceled |
| 1994 | Stich | 09/08/2021 | Pending |
| 1994 | Stich | 09/11/2021 | Approved |
| 1778 | leroy | 09/08/2021 | Approved |
| 1778 | leroy | 09/11/2021 | Transferred |

This is my current code -

```
SELECT a.Number, 
CASE WHEN a.Status = 'Approved' and  a.Status = 'Canceled' or a.Status = 'Transferred' 
THEN
(SELECT MAX(b.Name) 
FROM Internal_Table b 
WHERE a.Number = b.Number
AND b.Status != 'Canceled'
or b.Staus != 'Transfered'
HAVING MAX(b.Date) 
) 
ELSE a.Status END AS Final_Status, 
a.Date,
a.Name 
FROM Internal_Table a
```

The goal that I'm trying to achieve is to create a new Column that will say "Approved/Canceled" , "Approved/Transferred". But  o only when the "Canceled" or "Transferred" status is shown after the "Approved" date.  I'm not too familiar with using CASE so this is my current attempt. Sorry for any confusion.  This is how I would like my results to look =

| Number | Name | Date | Status | Final Stats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1789 | Brandon | 12/20/2021 | Pending |  |
| 1789 | Brandon | 12/22/2021 | Approved |  |
| 1553 | Jake | 10/05/2021 | Approved | approved/Canceled |
| 1553 | Jake | 11/10/2021 | Canceled | approved/Canceled |
| 1997 | Smith | 09/08/2021 | Approved | approved/Transferred |
| 1997 | Smith | 09/11/2021 | Transferred | approved/Transferred |
| 1338 | James | 11/05/2021 | Approved | approved/Canceled |
| 1338 | James | 11/10/2021 | Canceled | approved/Canceled |
| 1994 | Stich | 09/08/2021 | Pending |  |
| 1994 | Stich | 09/11/2021 | Approved |  |
| 1778 | leroy | 09/08/2021 | Approved | approved/Transferred |
| 1778 | leroy | 09/11/2021 | Transferred | approved/Transferred |

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: please only tag the database you are using

Comment: what does `select @@version;` show?

Comment: Are the dates stored as strings as in the published sample?

Comment: Ignore "Pending", group by `number` (or `name`? or both?), concatenate `status` per group while ordering by `date`, check if it contains "Approved/Canceled" or "Approved/Transferred" substring, leftjoin this to original table. For example...

Comment: Yes, the dates are stored as a string I believe @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

You should start by fixing your table so the dates are stored as dates instead of strings.

This should work -

```
SELECT b.*, t.final_stats
FROM Internal_Table b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Number,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(Status IN ('Approved', 'Canceled', 'Transferred'), Status, null) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%m/%d/%Y') SEPARATOR '/') final_stats
    FROM Internal_Table
    GROUP BY Number
    HAVING final_stats IN ('Approved/Canceled', 'Approved/Transferred')
) t ON b.Number = t.Number;
```